# Angular + Ionic, ng-options implement value tag in select options

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using `ng-options` on a `<select>` like this `ng-options="item.model for item in prodataSelect | unique:'model' "`

But I would like the `<value=""` tag of the generated options to contain the `item.id` instead of the autoincremental value use by ng-options.

How to achieve this ?

HTML:

```
<select id = "chosenmodel" class="button button-full button-dark" ng-model="selectedModel" ng-options="item.model for item in prodataSelect | unique:'model' "> 
  <option value="">Select a Model</option>
</select>

<a id="submitbutton" class="button button-block button-dark ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all" ng-click='launchCompute()' href="#/app/compute/result">Compute my board</a>
```

Each item in `prodataSelect` is an object :

```
{
  brand: "John",
  fun: "0",
  id: 1
},
{
  brand: "you",
  fun: "0",
  id: 185
},
{
  brand: "Ark",
  fun: "0",
  id: 17
},
```

Comment: `ng-options="item.id as item.model for item in prodataSelect"`

Comment: posting it as an answer, plz accept

Answer (score 1):

use below syntax

```
       `ng-options="item.id as item.model for item in prodataSelect"`
```

read more about it [here](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs/)

Answer (score 0):

Use *"track by item.id"* to set option value to id

`ng-options="item.id as item.model for item in prodataSelect track by item.id"`