# Set key value in ngOptions AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, ng-options

I am trying to create a select dropdown using ngOptions. How would I go about listing the city names as options in a select from the data below?

So the options would be:

```
<option>Perugia</option>
<option>New Brunswick</option>
<option>Vicenza</option>


{
    Perugia: {
        country: [
            "IT"
         ]
    },
    New Brunswick: {
        state: [
            "NJ"
        ]
    },
    Vicenza: {
        country: [
            "IT"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: [Below link I hope answer for your question. Good luck..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203652/angular-ionic-ng-options-implement-value-tag-in-select-options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a fiddle, check it

https://jsbin.com/jarepo/edit?html,js,output

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
  ng-options="name as name for (name, obj) in cities"
  ng-model="selected">
```

JS,

```
$scope.cities = {
  Perugia: {
    country: [
      "IT"
    ]
  },
  'New Brunswick': {
    state: [
      "NJ"
    ]
  },
  Vicenza: {
    country: [
      "IT"
    ]
  }
};
$scope.selected = "Perugia";
```